# Как показывать каждые 4 элемента списка по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Есть список товаров, 4 отображаются, остальные с `display: none`. Как по каждому клику на кнопку отображать еще по 4 товара? [Песочница](https://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/BVrvgL).

```css
.list {
  column-count: 4;
  list-style: none;
}
.list li:nth-of-type(n+5) {
  display: none;
}

.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
</ul>

<div class="btn-container">
  <a href="#close" class="button">Button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let showProduct = function() {
  let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  let count = 4;
  for (item of li) {
    if (getComputedStyle(item).display == 'none' && count > 0) {
      item.style.display = 'block';
      count--;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.list {
  column-count: 4;
  list-style: none;
}

.list li:nth-of-type(n+5) {
  display: none;
}

.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>

  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>

  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
</ul>

<div class="btn-container">
  <a href="#close" class="button" onclick="showProduct()">Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Приму ответ через несколько минут, раньше Stack не позволяет.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

> Есть список товаров, 4 отображаются, остальные с display: none. Как по каждому клику на кнопку отображать еще по 4 товара?

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('a.button');
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) { 
  var c = 0; // counter
  li.forEach(function (el, i) { 
    // Visibility test checking parent style.display null if 'none'
    if( el.offsetParent === null && c < 4){
      console.log(i, el.style.display = 'block');
      c++;
    } 
  })
})
```

```css
.list {
  column-count: 4;
  list-style: none;
}
.list li:nth-of-type(n+5) {
  display: none;
}

.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Product 1</li>
  <li>Product 2</li>
  <li>Product 3</li>
  <li>Product 4</li>
  
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
</ul>

<div class="btn-container">
  <a href="#close" class="button">Button</a>
</div>
```

- `HTMLElement.offsetParent` - берет близкого *родителя* проходит по *детским* элементам проверяет, если они отобаражается. Возвращает `null`, когда `style.display='none'`

Answer (score 2):

Ответы в принципе уже даны. Просто добавлю свои 5 копеек. Ну вдруг кому...

```js
const checkit=()=>{
  let noneCount=[...document.getElementsByTagName('li')].filter(e=>getComputedStyle(e).display=='none').length;
  [...document.getElementsByTagName('li')].map((e,i)=>{
    if (i>=noneCount&&getComputedStyle(e).display=='none') {
      e.style.display='block';
    }
  });
}
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click',checkit);
```

```css
.list {
  column-count: 4;
  list-style: none;
}
.list li:nth-of-type(n+5) {
  display: none;
}

.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Product 1</li>
  <li>Product 2</li>
  <li>Product 3</li>
  <li>Product 4</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
  <li>Product</li>
</ul>
<div class="btn-container"><a class="button" href="#close">Button</a></div>
```